# How to write call back method for jQuery tab add method

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

What would be a call back method for adding a Ajax jQuery tab?

Example:

```
url ="a.jsp";

jQuery("#featur").tabs("add",url,"bio" , modul); // Add tab and content.
```

After response was ready I need to call one more method like changeTextArea().

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used tabs before, but I believe you want the `loaded` option:

```
$('#example').tabs(
{
    load: function(event, ui)
    {
        // Do some stuff.
    }
});
```

See [this example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page) in the docs.